# Resample data to weekly data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, resampling

I need to resample my stock data from a daily to weekly format.
The DATA:

```
Date        Open            High            Low             Close
2007-09-17  4518.450195     4549.049805     4482.850098     4494.649902
2007-09-18  4494.100098     4551.799805     4481.549805     4546.200195
2007-09-19  4550.250000     4739.000000     4550.250000     4732.350098
2007-09-20  4734.850098     4760.850098     4721.149902     4747.549805
2007-09-21  4752.950195     4855.700195     4733.700195     4837.549805
```

The data has some missing values and have been imputed using a SimpleImputer

I have used this code for the resampling:

```
agg_dict = {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}
r_df = nifty_tr.resample('W-MON').agg(agg_dict)
```

The problem that I seem to be facing is that the output dataset i.e., r_df, includes various new dates(it starts from the beginning of the year 2007, instead of 2007-09-17, as available in the given data. The outout contains mostly null values with ocaasional values.
OUTPUT

```
Date        Open            High            Low             Close
2007-01-21  5021.500000     6011.950195     5001.350098     5866.450195
2007-01-28  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2007-02-04  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2007-02-11  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2007-02-18  5854.850098     5944.750000     5714.250000     5932.399902
2020-11-15  10334.299810    10545.099610    10334.000000    10458.400390
......
2020-11-22  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-11-29  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-12-06  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-12-13  12151.000000    12231.750000    9508.000000     9590.150391
```

The code I used to load the data is:

```
nifty = pd.read_csv('../Nifty.csv', index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
nifty.drop(['Volume','Adj Close'],axis=1,inplace=True)
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'mean')
nifty_tr = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(nifty), columns=nifty.columns, index=nifty.index)
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this to happen. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: it is expected when you use `resample('W-MON')` that you get all the Mondays between the dates. You can chain your command with `dropna('all')` to remove the dates that don't overlap with your data.

Comment: I didn't quite get that, you mean nifty_tr.resample('W-MON').agg(agg_dict).dropna('all')?

Comment: Yes, something like that will remove all the dates with `NaN` values.

Comment: but it would still contain values for additional rows such as '2007-01-21',etc. These seem to be new dates that have been interpolated by the resampling

Comment: Yes, because you sampled by `Monday`. So `2007-01-21` would contains the aggregation info for the week `2007-01-21--27`

Comment: even using resample('W'), returns the same result. I get that, 2007-01-21 would ocntain the aggregation for the week 2007-01-21 -- 27, but that date is not part of the input data frame. The dates start from 2007-09-17, So the first entry should be for the week 2007-09-17 -- 23

Comment: Have you considered doing it manually in Pandas:  retrieve the min, max, etc for each value, summarizing to the week?  Pandas has very powerful datetime tooling -- see: pandas datetime resample.  An example would have this syntax after converting dates using datetime.datetime: `new_df['min'].resample('W', how='min')`

Comment: tried that it still adds these unwanted dates into the output dataframe